# How to exclude/disable @Entity Annotation for particular class

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to disable @Entity Annotation for particular class.
Here is my sample code.

@Component
public class GenericDropDown{

```
private Integer id;
private String key;
private String value;
```

// Standard getter and setter

The above class is used for fetching data from multiple table for rendering different dropdown list from different tables.

How I can achieve this without @Entity Annotation

Here is my sample code.

@Component
public class GenericDropDown{

```
private Integer id;
private String key;
private String value;
```

// Standard getter and setter

@Repository
public class DropDownDao  {

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;


public Object runNativeQuery() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Priority> o= entityManager.createNativeQuery("select Id,PRKEY,PRVALUE from Priority",Priority.class)
     .getResultList();
   
   return o;
```

}

}
**Error:**Unknown entity: com.min.test.Project.entity.Priority; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.min.test.Project.entity.Priority

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select List of Objects array and map them yourself.

```
List<Object[]> o = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select Id,PRKEY,PRVALUE from Priority").getResltList();

List<MyClass> result = o.stream().map(arr -> new MyClass((Long) arr[0], (String) arr[1])).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or you also can use a JdbcTemplate instead of EntityManager:

```
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List<MyClass> runQuery() {
        String select = "select Id,yourParameterHere from Priority";

        return jdbcTemplate.query(select, (rs, rowNum) -> new MyClass(rs.getLong("Id"), rs.getString("yourParameterHere")));
    }
```